# SOLVED How did click on Flutter local notification depends on how app was opened before?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-navigation, flutter-local-notification

I'm facing a somehow strange issue with Flutter local notifications. When consuming/clicking on a local notification the response of my app seems to depend on how the app was opened before. This is what happens:

1. scenario (what does work as expected):

App is terminated -> open app manually -> app stays in foreground or background or is closed afterwards -> receive local notification -> click on local notification -> app is brought to foreground -> navigation to desired screen (`AddShoppingItemScreen`) happens

2. scenario (what does not work as expected):

App is terminated -> receive local notification -> click on local notification -> app is brought to foreground -> navigation to desired screen happens -> app stays in foreground or background -> receive another local notification -> click on local notification -> app is brought to foreground -> no navigation happens

I encountered this issue during testing my notifications on an Android emulator. Regardless of some other issues this works well on my attached iOS device.

Any idea on this?

Here is my code:

`main.dart`

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> onBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  debugPrint('App ist geschlossen');
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  LocalNotificationService().showMessagefromServer(message);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await LocalNotificationService().initialize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackgroundMessage);
  LocalStorage().initLocalStorage();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
      GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'Main Navigator');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ChangeListStatus(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`route_generator.dart`

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(
    RouteSettings settings,
  ) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const ShoppingItemListScreen());
      case '/add':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => AddShoppingItemScreen(
                  shoppingItem: args,
                ));
      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> _errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('ERROR'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('Page not found!'),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

`local_notifications_service.dart`

```
class LocalNotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@drawable/ic_launcher"),
      iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        requestAlertPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
      ),
    );

    final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
        await notificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    final didNotificationLaunchApp =
        notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false;

    if (didNotificationLaunchApp) {
      var payload = notificationAppLaunchDetails!.notificationResponse;
      onTapLocalNotification(payload!);
    } else {
      await notificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onTapLocalNotification,
      );
    }
  }

  void onTapLocalNotification(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
    final String? payload = notificationResponse.payload;
    debugPrint(payload);
    // this is where my navigation happens
    await MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(
      '/add',
      arguments: ShoppingItem(name: payload!, exist: null),
    );
  }

  Future<NotificationDetails> _notificationDetails() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      '01',
      'Local Notification',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );

    const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
        DarwinNotificationDetails(
            // presentAlert: true,
            // presentBadge: true,
            // presentSound: true,
            );

    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
      iOS: darwinNotificationDetails,
    );

    return notificationDetails;
  }

  Future<void> showLocalNotifications({
    required int id,
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String payload,
  }) async {
    final platformChannelSpecifics = await _notificationDetails();
    await notificationsPlugin.show(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: payload,
    );
  }

  void showMessagefromServer(RemoteMessage message) async {
    SharedPreferences store = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? deviceID = store.getString('deviceID');
    if (message.data['type'] == 'add') {
      // another class for getting data from my web server
      HttpServerConnection()
          .sendData(
        deviceID!,
        message.data['item'],
      )
          .then(
        (messages) {
          for (var message in messages['Messages']) {
            debugPrint(message['messageContent']);
            showLocalNotifications(
              id: messages['Messages'].indexOf(message),
              title: 'New Item',
              body: '${message['messageContent']} successfully recieved!',
              payload: message['messageContent'],
            );
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

`shopping_item_list_screen.dart` (my home screen)

```
class ShoppingItemListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShoppingItemListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ShoppingItemListScreen> createState() => _ShoppingItemListScreenState();
}

class _ShoppingItemListScreenState extends State<ShoppingItemListScreen> {
  final notificationService = LocalNotificationService();

  Future<void> initMessaging() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    debugPrint(token);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      debugPrint('Push Notification bei geöffneter App');
      LocalNotificationService().showMessagefromServer(message);

    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    notificationService.initialize();
    initMessaging();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

If you need more information please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

I found the part of the code that caused the issue: `notificationsPlugin.initialize()` nedds to be called regardless of the use of `didNotificationLaunchApp`. So I changed my code from

```
final didNotificationLaunchApp =
    notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false;

if (didNotificationLaunchApp) {
  var payload = notificationAppLaunchDetails!.notificationResponse;
  onTapLocalNotification(payload!);
} else {
  await notificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onTapLocalNotification,
  );
}
```

to

```
if (notificationAppLaunchDetails != null &&
    notificationAppLaunchDetails.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
  onTapLocalNotification(notificationAppLaunchDetails.notificationResponse);
}

await notificationsPlugin.initialize(
  initializationSettings,
  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onTapLocalNotification,
);
```

Now it works as expected.